# How to index tables for full outer join query based on date column in PostgreSQL 9.4?

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing

Lets say I have 3 tables with millions of rows.

```
CREATE TABLE blog (
  blog_id integer NOT NULL,
  blog_definition text,
  create_date timestamp without time zone,
  user_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT "Blog_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (blog_id)
);

CREATE TABLE blog_detail (
  blog_detail_id integer NOT NULL,
  blog_id integer,
  blog_header text,
  user_id integer,
  blog_content text,
  create_date timestamp without time zone,
  CONSTRAINT "Blog_Detail_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (blog_detail_id)
);

CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id integer NOT NULL,
  country text,
  user_name text,      
  CONSTRAINT "User_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

CREATE INDEX blog_create_date_user_id_blog_definition_idx
  ON blog
  USING btree
  (create_date, user_id, blog_definition COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

CREATE INDEX blog_detail_create_date_user_id_blog_content_blog_header_idx
  ON blog_detail
  USING btree
  (create_date, user_id, blog_content COLLATE pg_catalog."default", blog_header COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

CREATE INDEX users_country_user_id_idx
  ON users
  USING btree
  (country COLLATE pg_catalog."default", user_id);
```

And the query is like that.This query took 35 seconds with these indexes to get the results.

```
SELECT b.blog_definition, b.create_date, b.user_id, bd.blog_header,
       bd.blog_content, bd.user_id, bd.create_date 
FROM blog b 
FULL OUTER JOIN blog_detail bd ON b.create_date = bd.create_date 
WHERE CASE
  WHEN b.blog_id IS NULL THEN
    bd.user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE country = 'Greece') 
  WHEN bd.blog_id IS NULL THEN
    b.user_id IN (SELECT user_Id FROM users WHERE country = 'Greece')
  END
ORDER BY CASE 
  WHEN b.blog_id IS NULL THEN bd.create_date 
  WHEN bd.blog_id IS NULL THEN b.create_date 
  ELSE b.create_date
  END DESC
LIMIT 25;
```

Which columns in 3 tables do i need to index(and what kind of index) to get best query performance?

explain analyze results :

```
Limit  (cost=820038.99..820039.06 rows=25 width=50) (actual time=33047.344..33047.348 rows=25 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=820038.99..832538.93 rows=4999976 width=50) (actual time=33047.341..33047.343 rows=25 loops=1)
        Sort Key: (CASE WHEN (b.blog_id IS NULL) THEN bd.create_date WHEN (bd.blog_id IS NULL) THEN b.create_date ELSE b.create_date END)
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 26kB
        ->  Hash Full Join  (cost=191546.31..678943.27 rows=4999976 width=50) (actual time=3039.060..28832.090 rows=15000000 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (b.create_date = bd.create_date)
              Filter: CASE WHEN (b.blog_id IS NULL) THEN (hashed SubPlan 1) WHEN (bd.blog_id IS NULL) THEN (hashed SubPlan 2) ELSE NULL::boolean END
              ->  Seq Scan on blog b  (cost=0.00..173529.53 rows=9999953 width=22) (actual time=0.035..2090.918 rows=10000000 loops=1)
              ->  Hash  (cost=91666.89..91666.89 rows=4999989 width=28) (actual time=3003.440..3003.440 rows=5000000 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 8192  Batches: 128  Memory Usage: 2546kB
                    ->  Seq Scan on blog_detail bd  (cost=0.00..91666.89 rows=4999989 width=28) (actual time=0.008..1130.650 rows=5000000 loops=1)
              SubPlan 1
                ->  Index Only Scan using users_country_user_id_idx on users  (cost=0.56..1496.38 rows=41361 width=4) (actual time=0.050..4.007 rows=20000 loops=1)
                      Index Cond: (country = 'Germany'::text)
                      Heap Fetches: 0
              SubPlan 2
                ->  Index Only Scan using users_country_user_id_idx on users users_1  (cost=0.56..1496.38 rows=41361 width=4) (actual time=0.057..4.060 rows=20000 loops=1)
                      Index Cond: (country = 'Germany'::text)
                      Heap Fetches: 0
Planning time: 0.253 ms
Execution time: 33048.583 ms
```

Comment: Post your `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` results for a proper answer

Comment: @Patrick I added explain analyze results

Comment: Full outer joins are messy and not easy to index.  The purpose of indexes is to reduce the number pages read from disk (mostly).  To calculate the full outer join DBMS needs to read every row from both tables to get the right answer so an index is unlikely to help much.  In this case, the hash join that its using is pretty quick.

Comment: Quite remarkable that your query is about "Greece" and the query plan about "Germany"...

Comment: `WHERE CASE
  WHEN b.blog_id IS NULL THEN
    bd.user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE country = 'Greece') 
  WHEN bd.blog_id IS NULL THEN
    b.user_id IN (SELECT user_Id FROM users WHERE country = 'Greece')
  END` This is terrible. Could possibly be rewitten into two LEFT JOINS and a couple of COALESCE()s (or maybe a union) (or maybe even two EXISTS() conditions)

Comment: @Patrick country names didnt change the query time much.You can take Greece as Germany.

Comment: @joop then you are saying i should change the query right? Ok then what is the correct way to select the rows of both table according to user_id in that case?

Comment: @joop ok i will reconsider it.thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Couling commented to your question, `FULL JOIN`s tend to be problematic with indexes. That said, there is much to improve upon your query:

```
SELECT b.blog_definition, create_date, b.user_id, bd.blog_header,
       bd.blog_content, bd.user_id
FROM blog b 
FULL JOIN blog_detail bd USING (create_date) 
WHERE EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1 FROM users
   WHERE country = 'Greece' AND user_id = coalesce(bd.user_id, b.user_id))
ORDER BY create_date DESC
LIMIT 25;
```

- When you do a `JOIN` with the `USING` clause (instead of `ON`) then only one of the matching columns is included in the select list, so no need to use aliases. The convoluted `ORDER BY` clause was unnecessary anyway because `b.create_date` and `bd.create_date` are equal by virtue of the join.
- The `CASE WHEN` clause in the `WHERE` filter can also be avoided by using the `coalesce()` function and the obvious condition that either table has to have a value for `blog_id` and one for `user_id` too (otherwise your query would fail because the filter would evaluate to `WHERE NULL`). Since `b.blog_id` is the primary key of table `blog` it is therefore never `NULL` so by that same logic `b.user_id` could never be `NULL` and you could replace the `coalesce()` function with the column name. But that is left for you to ponder. If you look at your `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` you see that the very same sub-query gets evaluated twice (SubPlan 1 and SubPlan 2). This query will access table `users` only once. That's a proper 4ms saved! Plus another few ms because the sub-query is faster than in your code.
- The `create_date` field is a `timestamp`. Joining on `timestamp` equality is only possible if both records were created in the same session or when the value in one of the records is retrieved from the other record, such that their values are **exactly** the same.

You define an index on table `blog_detail`, but the index will be quite large because you include two potentially large text fields. Using an index on `create_date` alone will be much smaller (so fewer disk reads) and faster to process.

Comment: this approach decreased query time to 15 seconds.

Comment: Is that with the smaller index on just `create_date`?

Comment: Then that is probably as good as it gets. If you can update the `blog_details` table such that `blog_id` always refers to the right record in the `blog` table then you can use a regular join which will be much faster.